# How to use lineno with \intertext?

Tags: amsmath, line-numbering

I would like to number all lines of a document to help its reviewing.
The `lineno` package is working fine, except for the `\intertext{...}` paragraphs that I use between aligned equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{linenomath}
\begin{align}
x&=1\\
\intertext{More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.}
y&=2
\end{align}
\end{linenomath}

Last line.
\end{document}
```

[image: badly numbered lines]

Is there some way to fix this so that the three lines of my intertext paragraph are properly numbered?   (The only reason I use `\intertext` instead of a regular paragraph outside the `align` environment is that I wand to keep the
equations aligned.)

Comment: With all that text between, do you really need to align the equations?  There is a point where style ends and OCD begins.

Comment: In fact it's a single very long equation that I have split on multiple lines so that can describe each term as they are introduced.   Nevertheless the problem exists even if the `\intertext` is one single line.

Comment: I can't do anything about \intertext, but I can replace one align block with a bunch of aligned equations.

Comment: Actually, I CAN do something about \intertext.  The \MakeLineNo command will put a line number anywhere.  It also causes a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to align equations at a distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newlength{\SplitLeft} \setlength{\SplitLeft}{0pt}
\newlength{\SplitRight} \setlength{\SplitRight}{0pt}
\newlength{\SplitLen}
\newcounter{SplitSet}
\newcounter{SplitUsed}

\newcommand{\Split}[3] % #1 = command, #2 = counter, #3 = argument (if any)
 {\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname Split\Alph{#2}\endcsname{#3}}

\newcommand{\splitalign}[2]{ % #1 = left of alignmnet, #2 = right of alignment
 \stepcounter{SplitSet}
 \Split{newsavebox}{SplitSet}{}
 \Split{savebox}{SplitSet}{$\displaystyle{#1}$}
 \settowidth{\SplitLen}{\Split{usebox}{SplitSet}{}}
 \ifdim\SplitLeft<\SplitLen\setlength{\SplitLeft}{\SplitLen}\fi
 \stepcounter{SplitSet}
 \Split{newsavebox}{SplitSet}{}
 \Split{savebox}{SplitSet}{$\displaystyle{#2}$}
 \settowidth{\SplitLen}{\Split{usebox}{SplitSet}{}}
 \ifdim\SplitRight<\SplitLen\setlength{\SplitRight}{\SplitLen}\fi
}

\newcommand{\splitdisplay}[0]{
 \stepcounter{SplitUsed}
 \makebox[\SplitLeft][r]{\Split{usebox}{SplitUsed}{}}\,
 \Split{savebox}{SplitUsed}{}
 \stepcounter{SplitUsed}
 \makebox[\SplitRight][l]{\Split{usebox}{SplitUsed}{}}\,
 \Split{savebox}{SplitUsed}{}
 \ifnum\value{SplitUsed}=\value{SplitSet}\setcounter{SplitSet}{0}
  \setcounter{SplitUsed}{0} \setlength{\SplitLeft}{0pt} 
  \setlength{\SplitRight}{0pt}\fi
}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{linenomath}
\splitalign{x}{=1}
\splitalign{y}{=2}
\begin{equation}
\splitdisplay
\end{equation}
More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.\\
\begin{equation}
\splitdisplay
\end{equation}
\end{linenomath}

Last line.
\end{document}
```