# Two separate align in one direction in latex

Tags: align

I would like two write two different align with two different labels, but I want both of them
begin in one direction. How can I fix this code in latex?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,bm, mathtools}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \label{x}
    x = x + y + c
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
    \label{y}
    a + b + c = z + c + v + b
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Something like: [side-by-side equations, with equation numbers for each](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32701/5764)

Comment: what do you mean by begin in one direction? Also you have used `align` but you have specified no alignment points?

Comment: I want that the first equation position changes and goes a little bit to the left side which the second align starts.

Comment: Do you want `\begin{align}
\label{x}
&x = x + y + c \\
\label{y}
&a + b + c = z + c + v + b
\end{align}`

Comment: @rose sorry I have no idea what you mean by that. You could edit the output of your example in a paint program to move the equations to where you want and post that, then we could show how to change Tex to make that result.

Comment: Does your real example have more than one equation in each `align` otherwise there is nothing to align and you just want `\[ \]` `align` uses `&` like `tabular` to mark the cell boundaries your `align` are like a 1-row-1-column table, which is legal but pointless as it is simpler not to have a table at all.

Comment: You might also be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133286/how-to-use-lineno-with-intertext/133322#133322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math display environments of `amsmath` (`gather`, `align`, ...) allow one `\label` per equation line, see the example below.

However, it is not clear to me, how the alignment should look exactly. Thus here a few variations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,bm, mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{x1}
x &= x + y + c\\
\label{y1}
a + b + c &= z + c + v + b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\label{x2}
&x = x + y + c\\
\label{y2}
&a + b + c = z + c + v + b
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{x3}
&x &&= x + y + c\\
\label{y3}
&a + b + c &&= z + c + v + b
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]