# How can I center many equations without making a huge {align} or {alignat}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I want about 20 equations to be aligned, as there is never more than one line of text in between. I have used `{alignat}`, because I also want to have `\Rightarrow` in the beginning of some lines and didn't know how to align these and the "=" of the equations in any other way.
As I hit the end of a page I get an error, I assume because the `{align}` is treated as a table-like structure and cannot be taller than one page.
How can I solve this?

Is it possible to just force a "=" to be centered in an `{align}` or `{alignat}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To allow pagebreaks inside an `align` (or `align*`, `alignat`, `gather`, etc) environment, issue the directive `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: Just a thought is to use a \phantom command before the `=`  with  content  exactly the same as the real equation after the `=`... You also can use a phantom `\Rightarrow`... at the begining of first equation. This way the `=` will be almost centered without using align... etc

Comment: One way to align things is to put them into \makebox or \mathmakebox (mathtools) with the same width.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133286/how-to-use-lineno-with-intertext/133322?s=8|0.0546#133322

Comment: @Mico Thank you! That works just fine for my purpose. Do you also know how to make my \Rightarrow left-aligned? I am currently doing this


&\Rightarrow \quad &c_V \cdot ln(T) + R \cdot ln(V) &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &ln(T^{c_V} \cdot V^R) &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &T^{c_V} \cdot V^R &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &T^{c_V} \cdot V^\frac{R}{c_V} &= const.


If I put a && in the very beginning of each line the arrow stays in the same place, while the next part of the equation (between \Rigtharrow and "=") is left-aligned.

Comment: @camileri - Please post a new question. It's really hard to read the unformatted material placed in a comment.

Comment: @Mico
I wasn't aware formattiong works differently in comments. Thank you!
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391647/how-to-make-rightarrows-before-equations-left-aligned-while-keeping-the-rest-o