# How to make \Rightarrows before equations left-aligned, while keeping the rest of the equation centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignat

I am currently doing this:

```
\begin{alignat}{5}
&\Rightarrow \quad &c_V \cdot ln(T) + R \cdot ln(V) &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &ln(T^{c_V} \cdot V^R) &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &T^{c_V} \cdot V^R &= const.\\
&\Rightarrow &T^{c_V} \cdot V^\frac{R}{c_V} &= const.
\end{alignat}
```

If I put a `&&` in the very beginning of each line the arrow stays in the same place, while the next part of the equation (between `\Rigtharrow` and `=`) is left-aligned.

Comment: In better form: `From the fact that $c_V\ln T+R\ln V$ is constant, we easily deduce that also $T^{c_V}V^{R}$ is constant, as well as $TV^{R/c_V}$.`

Comment: If you're writing a research paper or a text for experts, displaying the steps is quite offensive to the readers; if you're writing a low level manual, perhaps displaying the steps is good. Anyway, your last step is incorrect and I fixed it in the comment above.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two variants, using the`\mathllap` command from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` since mathtools does it for you): in  the first one, the equations are really centred independently from `\rightarrow\quad`, in the second one, they're nearly centred, but slightly simpler to type.  B.t.w., you only need two alignment groups here (whence only `3&`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathllap{ ⇒ \quad} & & c_V · \ln(T) + R · \ln(V) &= \mathrm{const.} \\
\mathllap{ ⇒ \quad} & & \ln(T^{c_V} · V^R) &= \mathrm{const.} \\
\mathllap{ ⇒ \quad} & & T^{c_V} · V^R &= \mathrm{const.} .\\
\mathllap{ ⇒ \quad} & & T · V^{\tfrac{R}{c_V}} &= \mathrm{const.}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathllap{ ⇒ } & \quad & c_V · \ln(T) + R · \ln(V) &= \mathrm{const.} \\
\mathllap{ ⇒ } & & \ln(T^{c_V} · V^R) &= \mathrm{const.} \\
\mathllap{ ⇒ } & & T^{c_V} · V^R &= \mathrm{const.} .\\
\mathllap{ ⇒ } & & T · V^{\tfrac{R}{c_V}} &= \mathrm{const.}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: Right. I hadn't even read the details. I've fixed it. Is this site gradually turning into TeX+Math Stack Exchange? ;o)